# PHP Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Hi I'm a novice PHP developer to say the least and I'm pretty stuck.

I'm trying to get the below code working I know I need a foreach loop or similar but I'm way out of my depth, I'm really not sure how to get this working, I know to most of you this is basic stuff but I'm lost.

Basically this is a receipt when a tab is settled. It searches the MySql Database for the relevant items and should print them on the receipt.

I know the MySql Query is not linked to the output at the bottom but I don't know how to do it.

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Receipt</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <?php

   $invoicenum = $_POST['invoicenum'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];

   $netrev=$invoicenum - 1;

  ?>
  Items:
  <?
   $itemQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE invoicenum = '$netrev' AND tabname = '$name'");
 $result = array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($itemQuery))
 {
  $result[] = $row['itemname'];
 }

 echo json_encode($result);

   $amounts = json_decode($result['amounts']);
   $items = json_decode($result['items']);
   $prices = json_decode($result['prices']);
  ?>
   <br>
   <?
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++)
    {
     echo $amounts[$i] . "x " . $items[$i] . " - " . $prices[$i] . "<br>";
    }
   ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

I've removed code that isn't relevant to this array, if you can help I'd be forever grateful.

Comment: I'm unsure what you question is... What is the current output? What is the desired output? What is working? What isn't working as intended?

Comment: if `$result[]=$row['itemname']` why should `json_decode($result['amounts'])` work at all?

Comment: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE invoicenum = '$netrev' AND tabname = '$name'");` **WARNING WARNING - Danger Will Robinson!**  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php and http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: This `$result[]=` creates number indexes , so no string key is present in the array

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions I don't know, that's why I'm here

Comment: Why you are decoding stuff, they are not encoded

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but you should definitely look into mysqli and prepared statements, your SQL query is very vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes, mysql_ statements have been gone for 2 years.  Please look into mysqli.  As for your question, please elaborate.  It is unclear what the desired output is and where your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need of encode and decode.

```
$itemQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE invoicenum = '$netrev' AND tabname = '$name'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($itemQuery))
{
    echo $row['amounts'] . "x " . $row['items'] . " - " . $row['prices'] . "<br>";
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget all json_decode/encode after filling `$result` then:

First do:

`$result[] = $row;`

Then:

```
foreach ($result as $set){
   echo $set['amount'] . "x " . $set['itemname'] . " - " . $set['price'] . "<br>";
   #do var_dump($set); here for checking the keys
}
```